# Vonage Voice Api Calling Error : Exception has occurred: TypeError Expecting a PEM-formatted key

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, voice, vonage

```py
import os
from os.path import join, dirname
from pprint import pprint
from vonage import *
from dotenv import load_dotenv

dotenv_path = join(dirname(file), "../.env")
load_dotenv(dotenv_path)

VONAGE_APPLICATION_ID = os.environ.get("VONAGE_APPLICATION_ID")
VONAGE_APPLICATION_PRIVATE_KEY_PATH = os.environ.get("VONAGE_APPLICATION_PRIVATE_KEY_PATH")
VONAGE_NUMBER = os.environ.get("VONAGE_NUMBER")
TO_NUMBER = os.environ.get("TO_NUMBER")

client = vonage.Client(
application_id=VONAGE_APPLICATION_ID,
private_key=VONAGE_APPLICATION_PRIVATE_KEY_PATH,
)

voice = vonage.Voice(client)

response = voice.create_call({
'to': [{'type': 'phone', 'number': TO_NUMBER}],
'from': {'type': 'phone', 'number': VONAGE_NUMBER},
'ncco': [{'action': 'talk', 'text': 'This is a text to speech call from Nexmo'}]
})

pprint(response)
```

the error im receiving when running this code is :

````
Exception has occurred: TypeError
Expecting a PEM-formatted key.
File "C:\Users\mikea\Desktop\deleted\lil test\vonage-calls.py", line 25, in
'ncco': [{'action': 'talk', 'text': 'This is a text to speech call from Nexmo'}]```
````

Answer (score 0):

As per your error `Expecting a PEM-formatted key`, I think you are passing a path instead of a key. A **PEM** key should be some hash value.

Comment: ok i am going to try too look for a key but the error is highlight this line of code              'ncco': [{'action': 'talk', 'text': 'This is a text to speech call from Nexmo'}]

Comment: @Helpmepleasegang I'm not sure about the third key "**ncco**" in your response. The docs show something like "**answer_url**" in [Link](https://github.com/Vonage/vonage-python-sdk)

Comment: Also, avoid using "*" in your imports. Its good to be explicit in what you are going to use.